# Implicit conversion from int to enum class in switch statement

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, enum-class

```
enum class pid
{
    Alpha, Beta, Gamma
};

int main()
{
    int propId = 2;
    switch(propId)
    {
    case pid::Alpha:
    case pid::Beta:
    case pid::Gamma:
        break;
    }
}
```

Above snippet compiles fine in msvc2012 (and works) but fails in clang-3.4 and g++-4.8. These  require `static_cast<pid>(propId)` to be used inside switch clause.

Incidentally, simple assignment without explicit cast such as `pid a = propId;` gives error in each compiler.

Which one got it right?

Comment: does it matter, either way you have to code around it

Comment: Although it compiles, Intellisense in VC++2013 marks it as an error.

Comment: AFAIK, Intellisense uses EDG compiler's frontend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard Clause 4, "standard conversions", only every lists *unscoped* enumerations. Therefore, strong enums do *not* have any standard conversions, and you must use the `static_cast` in either direction.

You could argue that this sort of explicitness is the entire point of the strong enums. They do not act as integers at the drop of a hat, but rather require explicit declaration of intent. Note [thanks, @DyP] that `switch` statements explicitly support strong enums and do *not* require a manual conversion to some integral type.

Comment: You could also quote [stmt.switch].

Comment: Actually, it would be neat if the standard defined a static member `at()` that would convert an underlying-type value into the enum in question and throw a range exception.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No seriously - *everyone* and their dog reinvent wheels to validate and print enums. At least the validation part can be done better by the compiler than by reinvention, don't you think?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yeah but I wish people wouldn't use enums like that _at all_. I see benefits when de-serialising and that's about it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sometimes you are interfacing with other languages that do not have enums. You get an input integer, that you want to convert to an enum, cause you like to use those in your C++ code. Then you are force to use a switch statement, while something like `template<typename EType> EType std::to_enum<EType>(typename std::unerlying_type<EType>::type i)` would help..

Comment: I'm not arguing for this feature to be added somewhere in the library. I just saw your comment, and I just thought I'd point out a case where one *does* use enums like that. I agree that it is a corner case. Still, some of us need to deal with cross language code a lot. :)